# Access java object from JSP inside javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a jsp page which contains an object Person. I need to access the Person object inside javascript.

My JSP code

```
<%
 Person person = new Person();
 person.setName("Towhid");
 person.setAddress("BD");
%>
<script>
    var person;
</script>
```

Comment: Don't mix and match the different levels of execution. The JSP code is server-side technoloiy and evaluated at the server-side. The server generates the HTML page and sends it to the client. At this time the JSP code isn't part of the HTML anymore and the server objects are gone. Vue is client-side technology. It is executed inside the browser after the browser received the response (which was generated by JSP). Although the JSP code and JS code parts are side-by-side, there are totally unrelated. You can generate JS code with JSP but you cannot access the JSP person instance in your JS code.

Comment: I want to pass the object somehow

Answer (score 1):

The code between within the JSP tags only exists on the server. It it not available in the HTML sent to the client.

To access the `Person` data in the Vue object, you need to "print" the Person data into the script tag. For example:

```
<%
 Person person = new Person();
 person.setName("Towhid");
 person.setAddress("BD");
%>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          personName: '<%=person.getName()%>'
          personAddress: '<%=person.getAddress%>'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Note that this approach is a demonstration of how it *can* be done, but not how it *should* be done. The approach above is vulnerable to XSS attacks because the hand-crafted JSON data is not properly escaped. To do this properly, you need to either use a JSP tag to escape the person content to JSON, or use a serialization technique that can provide the person data as JSON.

Comment: I want to assign the whole object as I have many entities inside a single object

Comment: You will JSON serialization scheme then. There are many libraries available for this, for example https://github.com/google/gson Then in your data block you could do something like: `person: <%=person.toJson()%>` (With Gson it would be `gson.toJson(person)`